# Indesign Table of Contents empty

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I create a Table of Contents based on my chapter title paragraph style, the ToC header appears with no other text. Meaning the chapters and chapter numbers aren't generated.

The story I'm placing my ToC in is not linked to the main body story.

How can I get my ToC generated?

Comment: .... and the chapter titles actually have the paragraph style applied to them?

Comment: Yes, I also added a new style and applied to all headings to try it again from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

(We don't have many details to go by, so this is a guess.)

Your problem might be that you are using the *Same style* for the entries as for your headers:

[image: TOC]

If your headers are very large or are using *Keep Options* etc., there might not be room for them in the text frame containing the TOC.

Does the text frame with the TOC have overset text?